# Python Pandas read_csv(encoding='utf16') only works with engine='python'?

Tags: python, pandas, utf-16

I am using Pandas 0.18.1 on Python 2.7.10 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.2 and am having trouble reading UTF-16 files with [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if I do not set `engine='python'`.

The documentation states that the Python parser is more feature-complete, so it's possible that Pandas is trying to use the C parser by default, and that it does not yet support UTF-16. Can someone confirm whether this is the case, or whether there is something else happening here?

Below is a minimal reproduction scenario:

```
alanwagner : ~ ∴ pip2.7 freeze | grep pandas
pandas==0.18.1
alanwagner : ~ ∴ cat test.csv 
col1,col2
val1,val2
alanwagner : ~ ∴ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf8').to_csv('test-utf16.csv', encoding='utf16', index=False)
>>> 
alanwagner : ~ ∴ cat test-utf16.csv 
??col1,col2
val1,val2
alanwagner : ~ ∴ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('test-utf16.csv', encoding='utf16')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 315, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 799, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1213, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 520, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:5129)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 701, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:7665)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x63 in position 2: truncated data
>>> pd.read_csv('test-utf16.csv', encoding='utf16', engine='python')
   col1  col2
0  val1  val2
>>>
```

I was able to work around this by converting my file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 before loading it into a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you try to use `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` or `encoding='cp1252'` (I think 1252 will definitely fail but just a shot in the dark).

Comment: Seems to me that you will be helped with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690122/pandas-read-csv-and-utf-16

Comment: And here is another one discussion https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/739

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's true!
You can instead try just -

```
pd.read_csv('test-utf16.csv', encoding='utf-16')
```

I haven't dug up to find why this works, but this should let you read it without setting the engine.