# How to sort a csv file column by newest time

Tags: python, date, sorting, csv, time

I am trying to read in a csv file which is a result from running [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) autorunsc command line (i.e., autorunsc -a -m -c > mycsv.csv) and sort it by time in a way which I get the newest date/time at the top like it does in excel.

I have so far figured out how to convert it the csv file without an encoding error by reading it in as UTF16 using [Recoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177820/python-utf-16-csv-reader) python class to reencode it as utf 8.

```
import sys
import csv
import operator
import codecs

class Recoder(object):
    def __init__(self, stream, decoder, encoder, eol='\r\n'):
        self._stream = stream
        self._decoder = decoder if isinstance(decoder, codecs.IncrementalDecoder) else codecs.getincrementaldecoder(decoder)()
        self._encoder = encoder if isinstance(encoder, codecs.IncrementalEncoder) else codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoder)()
        self._buf = ''
        self._eol = eol
        self._reachedEof = False

    def read(self, size=None):
        r = self._stream.read(size)
        raw = self._decoder.decode(r, size is None)
        return self._encoder.encode(raw)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._reachedEof:
            raise StopIteration()
        while True:
            line,eol,rest = self._buf.partition(self._eol)
            if eol == self._eol:
                self._buf = rest
                return self._encoder.encode(line + eol)
            raw = self._stream.read(1024)
            if raw == '':
                self._decoder.decode(b'', True)
                self._reachedEof = True
                return self._encoder.encode(self._buf)
            self._buf += self._decoder.decode(raw)
    next = __next__

    def close(self):
        return self._stream.close()


writer = open('mycsv1.csv, 'wb')
f = open('mycsv.csv','rb'):
sr = Recoder(f, 'utf-16', 'utf-8')
s = sorted(csv.reader(sr), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True))

for row in s:
    print >> writer, row[0], ",", row[1], "," row[2]
```

The issue is this only sorts it by the month from the looks of it.  Say I had entries for months 1 - 6 for years 2010, 2011, 2012.

It would sort it by the month only and not include the time or date so that I get the newest dates only.  Instead I get 1/1/2010, 1/1/2011, 1/1/2012, 2/1/2010, 2/1/2011, 2/1/2012.

If I sort it in excel, it will give me the newest dates/times first which in the case if it was based on this month of June (6/1/2012, 5/1/2012, 4/1/2012, etc.)  Any help on how can I accomplish this using python is most appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The sample data I am working with is from autorunsc after its been formatted to utf8.  The data in the CSV should be as follows:

```
Time, Entry Location, Entry, Enabled, Category, Description, Publisher, Launch String
6/23/2011 14:23, HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services, JavaQuickStarterService, enabled, Services, Prefetches JRE files for faster startup, Oracle Corporation, C:\Program Files\java, C:\Program Files\Java\jre\blah
5/25/2006 1:14,,,,,,,,,
4/4/2003 22:10,,,,,,,,,
4/17/2006 11:11,,,,,,,,
0,,,,,,,,, (Some of the entries do not have date values and are null or blank.
6/10/2013 9:30,,,,,,,,,
6/23/2013 10:25,,,,,,,,,
etc
```

Most of these entries have values, but I didn't want to copy and paste everything.  I basically want to sort the dates from newest date/time like excel does.  The lambda option someone mentioned below errors out because it is reading in "Time" from the column first.  I want to figure out how to skip the first row and use lambda on the other date/time values to sort appropriately.

Comment: If the csv itself isn't sorted and autorunsc doesn't have an option to sort the output, you'll have to read the whole file then do the sorting in Python.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do now, see the code above, but all I get is sorting by the month as a result.  I am looking to get it in order by newest like excel does.

Comment: Didn't really get the question. Is the date/time field one of the columns in the CSV? If so, that should be straightforward. Read CSV line by line (`for line in file(filename).readlines()`), split each line at the comma (`line.split(',')`) to create a list of strings. You may now convert the date/time column into a `datetime` field and use `sorted`.

Comment: Yes, the fields are in the CSV at the top. I will update above to make it easier to understand what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Ok, didn't fully understand what was going on before. You problem is that your "dates" are still strings and being sorted as such. I'm guessing your date format is Month/Day/Year (US date style) as you say it's sorted by Month. All you need to do is parse your dates into datetime objects to solve your sorting problem.

```
# add this import at the top of your file
from datetime import datetime

# replace your current call to sorted with:
s = sorted(csv.reader(sr), key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0],"%m/%d/%Y"), reverse=True))
```

Comment: I did see this option before, but how do you skip over the name of the columns?  For example, the autorunsc generates the csv file with a header for each column.  The very first column has a name of "Time", so if I do what you suggest above, it comes back and gives me an error for reading in the value of "Time" since it is the first value of that column.  How do I skip that value and concentrate on actual date/time values?

Comment: @user2292661 so inside the lambda, the `x[0]` just references the first column in the row. Just replace the 0 with whichever column the date is contained in. If you could provide a sample row from the csv that would help a lot. I just went with 0 because you were using `itemgetter(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pandas** module and **to_datetime()** method.

**Code :**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

data = data.sort_values(by='Time', ascending=False)
print(data.to_csv(index=False))
```

**Input :** mycsv.csv

```
Time, Field
6/23/2011 14:23, ABC
5/25/2006 1:14, XYZ
4/4/2003 22:10, PQR
4/17/2006 11:11,GHI
, 0
, 1
6/10/2013 9:30, 2
6/23/2013 10:25, 3
```

**Output :**

```
Time, Field
2013-06-23 10:25:00, 3
2013-06-10 09:30:00, 2
2011-06-23 14:23:00, ABC
2006-05-25 01:14:00, XYZ
2006-04-17 11:11:00,GHI
2003-04-04 22:10:00, PQR
, 0
, 1
```