# Coerce UTF bytestream to ASCII

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am aware that `csv` won't handle UTF directly, and that part of the solution is to open the file using `codecs` which opens the stream using the right encoding. I still get the error however:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 121: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to process the byte stream from infile, coercing it to ascii before it is handed over to `csv.DictReader`? Thanks.

```
 with( codecs.open( infileName , 'rU', 'utf-16') ) as infile:
     rdr = csv.DictReader( infile , delimiter='\t' )
     vnames = rdr.fieldnames
     for row in rdr:
         do_something(row)
```

Comment: The `csv` module still handles *bytestrings* only; it is trying to encode the unicode values *back to byte strings*. In other words, your approach is never going to work.

Comment: Open the file as a bytestream instead with using regular `open()`.

Comment: If by "coerce" you mean "remove any characters which are not 7-bit", that is not hard to do. Hint: `ord()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Opening it with regular `open` isn't going to work. `csv` handles *ASCII-compatible* byte strings only; UTF-16 doesn't qualify.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, I realised that; contemplating VTCing this as a dupe of [Python UTF-16 CSV reader](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9177820).

Comment: As a side note, for Python 2.7, you may want to consider `io.open` instead of `codecs.open`. There are some cases for which their behavior differs, and in those cases you have to decide which behavior you want. But in most cases, they do effectively the same thing, and `io` has been getting improvements and bug fixes for the last 6 years (because it's the main interface to files in Python 3.x, and some things have been ported back), while `codecs` has not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It does seem pretty similar. And really, Mark Tolonen's answer there is a nice, simple solution to this poster's problem (although it's not the accepted answer, and it would be nice to have a little more than one line and a link).

Comment: @abarnert: I was toying with [`codecs.StreamRecoder()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamRecoder) as well, but the API is a little.. verbose.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: There's an example somewhere in the Python 3 docs of using the `io` module to do the rough equivalent of `StreamRecoder` but simpler. But really, the `UTF8Recoder` in the `csv` examples is all you need for this case, because `csv` doesn't care about the whole file-like interface, just `next`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Or, really, just `(line.encode('utf-8') for line in infile)`… I suspect that example was written back in 2.3 and not updated for generator expressions in 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that "`csv` won't handle UTF directly"; *nothing* in Python handles UTF directly, and you wouldn't want it to. When you want Unicode, you use Unicode; when you want a particular encoding (whether UTF-8, UTF-16, or otherwise), you have to use strings and keep track of the encoding manually.

---

Python 2.x `csv` can't handle Unicode, so the easy way is ruled out. In fact, it only understands bytes strings, and always treats them as ASCII. However, it doesn't tamper with anything other than the specific characters it cares about (delimiter, quote, newline, etc.). So, as long as you use a charset whose `,`, `"`, and `\n` (or whatever special characters you've selected) are guaranteed to be encoded to the same byte as in ASCII, and nothing else will ever be encoded to those bytes, you're fine.

Of course you don't just want to create a CSV file in any arbitrary charset; you presumably want to consume it in some other program—Excel, a script running on a server somewhere, whatever—and you need to create a CSV file in the charset that other program expects. But if you have control over the other program (e.g., it's Excel, and you know how to select the charset in its Import command), UTF-8 is almost always the best choice.

At any rate, UTF-16 does not qualify as a CSV-friendly charset, because, e.g., `,` is two bytes, not one.

---

So, how do you deal with this? The [Examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) in the documentation have the answer. If you just copy the `unicode_csv_reader` function and use it together with `codecs.open`, you're done. Or copy the `UnicodeReader` class and pass it an `encoding`.

But if you read the code for the examples, you can see how trivial it is: Decode your UTF-16, re-encode to UTF-8, and pass that to the `reader` or `DictReader`. And you can reduce that to one extra line of code, `(line.encode('utf-8') for line in infile)`. So:

```
with codecs.open(infileName , 'rU', 'utf-16') as infile:
    utf8 = (line.encode('utf-8') for line in infile)
    rdr = csv.DictReader(utf8, delimiter='\t')
    vnames = rdr.fieldnames
    for row in rdr:
        do_something(row)
```

---

Finally, why is your existing code raising that exception? It's not in the UTF-16 decoding. It's because you're passing the resulting `unicode` strings to code that wants a bytes `str`. In Python 2.x, that pretty much always means to automatically encode it with the default encoding, which defaults to ASCII, which is what raises the error. And that's why you have to explicitly encode to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks abarnert, Martijn. That's a lot to chew; my thinking about the encoding processing was off. I'll step through the process.

Comment: @user2808321: You pretty much always have to think through the encoding process, especially when your input and output charset is something non-ASCII-friendly like UTF-16. Unless, of course, you upgrade to Python 3.x.